# Passing extra parameters to foldRight

Tags: scala, scala-2.8, scala-collections

Is there a way to pass some extra parameter to the function that is provided to Scala's List.foldRight?

Some example code:

```
def createActorPool[T](implicit actor: Manifest[T], poolSize: Int): List[Supervise] = {
  (1 to poolSize).foldRight(List[Supervise]()) {
    (idx, list) => { Supervise(actorOf[actor], Permanent) :: list }
  }
}
```

The object I am interested in is `actor`, which is however not visible when being used to construct Supervise.

P.S.: I'm pretty new to Scala, so please accept my apologies if this is a FAQ (despite extensive googling without any applicable hits).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I don't really get your problem.
The function passed to foldRight is free to reference and use anything else you have in scope.
Isn't that enough ?

Comment: Hm... It is. Probably I misinterpreted a compiler error message (the IDEA Scala plugin complained about an unresolvable symbol), so I was under the impression that actor wouldn't be visible. Thanks for clarifying this!

Answer (score 2):

In Scala, the characters `[` and `]` are only used for types. In the code sample you provided, `actor` is an object, not a type. Perhaps this will work:

```
def createActorPool[T](implicit actor: Manifest[T], poolSize: Int): List[Supervise] = {
  (1 to poolSize).foldRight(List[Supervise]()) {
    (idx, list) => { Supervise(actorOf[T], Permanent) :: list }
  }
}
```